# JQuery Mobile blank page on load

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am attempting integrate jQuery Mobile into an existing mobile page. I want to use the collapsible element, and form features.

When I include the js file, and load the page, the page is rendered blank. When it is not included it is rendered correctly. I have added `data-role="page"` and "content" as below:

Looking in Firebug I see the body element has the `'ui-mobile-viewport'` class on it and it's visibility is set to hidden; its child elements have `display = none`.

I am getting this error in the console when debugging (line 5014) of jquery-mobile-1.0.1.js:

```
    $el.prop is not a function
        if ( $el.prop("disabled") ) {
```

Code below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title><%=PageTitle%></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=CssPath%>/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=JsPathShared%>/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=JsPath%>/page.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=JsPath%>/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 100);">
<div data-role="page" id="page-wrap" >
<header>
  <%RenderBanner();%>

</header>
<div data-role="content" class="section-wrap">

  <%Render();%>
  <footer>
    <nav>
      <%RenderNavigation();%>
    </nav>
    <%RenderFooter();%>
  </footer>
</div>
</div>
<%=GoogleAnalytics()%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any errors in the console? link to demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider checking out the jQuery Mobile Boilerplate project from Github. It contains a complete jQuery Mobile project along with code snippets you can use to compare your code to a working project.

https://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Boilerplate

Comment: This was selected as the answer, but with no explanation. Can you let us know what the solution actually was?

Comment: Yes please. I have this trouble too